# Magento 2 Commerce : How to get the customer segments associated with current customer?

Tags: magento2, customer, magento-2-commerce, customer-segmentation

How do I get the customer segments associated with current logged in customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get matched segments of a customer directly from customer session, these are compiled during reindexing and associated to the customer while it's session is created. So, we can get it from customer session object [`Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory`]

```
$matchedCustomerSegments = $this->_customerSessionFactory->create()->getCustomerSegmentIds()
```

With above code you'll get array of the website ids in the first index and matched segments corresponding to them. Such as below;

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

In above case the customer has been matched to segment_ids 1 and 2 corresponding to website_id 1.

Also if you want to get whether the customer has matched with a specific segment instead of segment_id you can use segment collection [`Magento\CustomerSegment\Model\ResourceModel\Segment\Collection`] to get the data as following;

```
$matchedCollection = $this->_segmentModelCollection->addFieldToFilter(
            'segment_id',
            [
                ['1','2']
            ])->addFieldToFilter(
            'name',
            'Segment Name'
        );
```